# curl different result when I call it from ruby via backtick `curl <url>`

Tags: ruby, curl, ssl

I would like to use curl to access https url but I always have error message...
my one line code is

```
`curl https://www.google.com`
```

but when I run I got

```
"curl: (1) Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl".
```

Anyway, I try calling curl manually on command prompt and it is working fine.
So I try...

```
C:>curl https://www.google.com
```

and I can have..

```
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.co.th/?gws_rd=cr&amp;ei=FAe5U62VBMWdugSNvoHIAg">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Note that I have already download curl version 7.21.7 which is support SSL but I still have the same error.

Could you have any advise ?

**Update**
I try using open3. It sitll did not work but this time it shows
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: https

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'open3'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> cmd = 'curl https:\\rubygems.org'
=> "curl https:\\rubygems.org"
irb(main):003:0> Open3.popen3(cmd) do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_hr|
irb(main):004:1* puts "stdout is: " + stdout.read
irb(main):005:1> puts "stderr is: " + stderr.read
irb(main):006:1> end
stdout is:
stderr is:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: https
=> nil
```

Comment: Could it be you are running Ruby (file or irb/pry) and *normal command* from a different directories? Try to change directory to, for example, C and run irb/pry from that, and try this command in backticks. Anyways, depending on your OS (I think you are using Windows) you may try other methods from the Ruby: http://mentalized.net/journal/2010/03/08/5_ways_to_run_commands_from_ruby/ Last 2 or 3, as fair I remember, was *nix only, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Yes. I run the script and manual command in the same directoty. I also tried both    system('curl <https://www.google.com>') and     exec('curl <https://www.google.com>) are still show the same error message. But when I change to http instead of https I can get html body when I run ruby.

Comment: Try this: `\`cmd /c curl https://www.google.com\``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spend sometime, I observe that my ruby always call curl.exe from C:\Windows\SysWOW64 (I don't know why ??) and it is curl v7.32.0 x86_64-pc-win32. I guess this one is not with ssl enable. While another curl.exe in C:\Windows\win32 is v7.21.7 which I know that it is with ssl. --> This should be the root cause that I have dependency result.

I eventually to download and install the latest version of curl with ssl, v7.37.0.
It is now working fine either I run from backticks or manual way in command line. Problem fixed.